# Rails server or Rails s is not working when working with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following a long a tutorial and get the following output when I run rails s. I am able to use rail new.

I have tried both rails server and rails s. Also confirmed I ran bundle install prior to using rail s.

```
      Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

    Options:
          [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]              # Skip namespace (affects only     isolated applications)
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                          # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                             # Default: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                                  # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                                  # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/postgresql/sqlite3/oracle/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                             # Default: sqlite3
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]                  # Don't create a Gemfile
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                          # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                      # Skip source control .keep files
  -M, [--skip-action-mailer], [--no-skip-action-mailer]      # Skip Action Mailer files
      [--skip-action-mailbox], [--no-skip-action-mailbox]    # Skip Action Mailbox gem
      [--skip-action-text], [--no-skip-action-text]          # Skip Action Text gem
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]      # Skip Active Record files
      [--skip-active-storage], [--no-skip-active-storage]    # Skip Active Storage files
  -P, [--skip-puma], [--no-skip-puma]                        # Skip Puma related files
  -C, [--skip-action-cable], [--no-skip-action-cable]        # Skip Action Cable files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]              # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                    # Don't install Spring application preloader
      [--skip-listen], [--no-skip-listen]                    # Don't generate configuration that depends on the listen gem
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]            # Skip JavaScript files
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]            # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test], [--no-skip-test]                        # Skip test files
      [--skip-system-test], [--no-skip-system-test]          # Skip system test files
      [--skip-bootsnap], [--no-skip-bootsnap]                # Skip bootsnap gem
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                                  # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--rc=RC]                                              # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                                # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--api], [--no-api]                                    # Preconfigure smaller stack for API only apps
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                    # Don't run bundle install
  --webpacker, [--webpack=WEBPACK]                           # Preconfigure Webpack with a particular framework (options: react, vue, angular, elm, stimulus)
      [--skip-webpack-install], [--no-skip-webpack-install]  # Don't run Webpack install

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

    Example:
        rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

        This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
```

I have attempted this on both redhat distribution and amazon linux.

Comment: Did you double-check that you run the `rails s` command while being _in_ the application folder? Not on the level on which you created the application.

Comment: @spickermann is right. I reproduced this by run rails s outside of the application folder.

Comment: Yes I double checked this

Answer (score 0):

If nothing really helps, try to run the server with the absolute path.

First, find out where your rails command is located:

```
which rails
```

I'm using MacOS which gives me

```
alex@Alexs-MBP ~ % which rails
/Users/alex/.rbenv/shims/rails
```

Let's say your application directory (where the Gemfile etc. is) is located at

```
/Users/alex/Desktop/app
```

You can now cd into that directory and simultaneously call the rails program with

```
cd /Users/alex/Desktop/app && /Users/alex/.rbenv/shims/rails s
```

Just replace both paths before and after the '&&' with your correct paths.

Otherwise, make sure to be in a directory of an actual rails application before you start the server.

Hope this helps :)

Cheers,
Alex